# MVC Chart with IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, charts

Im trying to create a chart from some values from a database.

So far I want to create the chart with the following values

```
public class Acqusition{
public double Sum {get; set;}
public double Chance {get; set;}
```

So the Code I got so far:

```
var acquisitions = from ac in db.Acquisitions 
                       select ac;
foreach (var a in acquisitions)
{
    sums.Add(a.Sum.ToString());
}
foreach (var a in acquisitions)
{
    chances.Add(a.Chance.ToString());
}

if (acquisitions != null)
{
    var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 300)
                  .AddTitle("Acquisitions")
                  .AddSeries(
                     chartType: "Bubble",
                     name: "AcquisitionChart",
                     xValue: new[] { chances[0], chances[1], chances[2] },
                     yValues: new[] {sums[0], sums[1], sums[2]});
                     //xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
                    //yValues: chances);

     return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
 }
```

What I am looking for is a chart that is sorted by the chances values. Somehow I have the feeling once I know the solution its quite easy but I cant seem to get it right.

PS: System.Web.Helpers.Chart is the one im using

Greetings

Comment: sorted by chances values, you mean this: `xValues: chances.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()`?

Comment: @JeffreyZhang kinda yes but the sum value has to be sorted in the same way then otherwise the data gets comprimised on the chart. I want to display the acquisitions (1 bubble for each acquisition) on the chart sorted by the chance of the acquisition.

Comment: Okay got the sorting now quite easy with `acquisitions = acquisitions.OrderBy(o => o.Chance);`
The only problem that I have now left is how to create the chart that it shows all the values

Comment: What way you want to show the chart? image?

Comment: @JeffreyZhang yes as an Image as in the code in the question. Displaying it works fine only problem I have is to fill the xValue and the yValues with lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var acquisitions = from ac in db.Acquisitions
                   order by ac.Chance 
                   select ac;
foreach (var a in acquisitions)
{
    chances.Add(a.Chance.ToString());
    sums.Add(a.Sum.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it now slightly different (see comment above).
But the problem I still have and cant get my head around is how to display all the values in the chart.